2003 Buick rendezvous
I have 2003 Buick rendezvous I've replaced gas lines fuel filter heater core thermostat and my 2003 Buick rendezvous stalls at stop signs jerks going down the road my rpm just spins when it jerks please help my only transportation for work I don't know what else to try

Mileage? Diagnosing and troubleshooting EFI systems are generally not diy friendly unless familiar with sensors and engine computer running the engine.
